# Не отоброжается загруженная в папку media картинка в Django

Tags: html, django

Я пишу отдельную страницу с более подробной информацией о турах, предлагаемых тур агентством. Мне надо вывести загруженную картинку в `media` папку. Что мне нужно сделать для этого?

`urls.py` (`urls.py` главного проекта):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

`urls.py` приложения:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

app_name = "core"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("blog", views.blog, name = "blog"),
    path('email', views.email, name = 'email'),
    path("blog-single", views.blogSingle, name = "blogSingle"),
    path("tour-details/<int:ID>", views.portfolioDetails, name = "portfolioDetails"),
    path('success', views.success, name = 'success'),
    path('mailist', views.mailist, name = 'mailist'),
]   + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

функция из `views.py`, отвечающая за эту страницу:

```
def portfolioDetails(request, ID):
    relevant_tour = Tour.objects.get(id = ID)
    context = {"tour":relevant_tour}
    return render(request, 'core/tour-details.html', context)
```

`models.py` тура;

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="tours/")
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, related_name="continents")
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, related_name= "continents", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`html` код страницы:

```
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <img src= "media/{{tour.image}}" class="img-fluid tour-image" alt="Проверьте ваше интернет соединение">
    </div>
```

Вместо обычной картинки просто отоброжается `alt` текст.

Comment: Во-первых, `src="{{ tour.image.url }}"` а во-вторых, DEBUG включен?

Comment: @andreymal да, включен. url вставил, но все еще не показывает

Comment: Что пишет если открыть url картинки напрямую в отдельной вкладке?

Comment: @andreymal вы были правы насчет `url`, мне просто надо было убрать `media/` из `src`. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Надо было убрать `media/` из `src` и добавить к `{{tour.image}}` `url`. Таким образом, итоговый код будет выглядеть так: `{{tour.image.url}}`